# Как использовать другой компилятор в CLion в Linux?

Tags: c++, debian, g++, mingw, clion

Например, я хочу собрать под Linux'ом exe-шник. MinGW для g++ это позволяет сделать(ведь да?). Как это сделать? Да, можно зайти в Windows и собрать проект там, но вопрос в том, можно ли собрать exe под Linux'ом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLion использует cmake для описания проекта. Там можно указать `set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /path/to/cc)` и `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /path/to/cpp)`, это по вопросу про другой компилятор. А компилить .exe под линуксом можно с помощью того же mingw.